# Getting the SQLException message returned in XML package?

Tags: java, sql, servlets, exception

I am currently trying to debug my Java servlet which is having problems interfacing with a JDBC connection pool.

Note: my servlet was working fine three days ago but now its stopped working so I am assuming its my Sun One webserver or Database problem but with no error message I have no idea what is happening.

My servlet normally returns an XML response through the browser but with this error that is happening I am getting nothing returned just a black file.

After painstakingly putting breakpoints in my code I have isolated where the error occurs but I have no information being returned on this error.

It occurs at this line in my getData() method.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

Here is the full database class

**DatabaseLogic Class**

```
    public class DatabaseLogic
{
    private static Connection conn;

    public static void openDatabase() throws IOException, SQLException,
            NamingException
    {


        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        // servlet looks up for a connection pool called "jdbc/POOL"
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/POOL");
        // connection is then made/requests to connection pool

        try
        {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            String message = "Unable to connect to archive database : " + e;
            XMLBuilder.dbError(message);            
        }
    }


    public static String getData(String queryId, int requestNumber)
            throws SQLException
    {
        String result = "";
        if (queryId != null)
        { 

            try
            {

                // prepare a statement for use in query;
                try
                {
                    result = "This is where it breaks";
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    result = "This message does not get returned";

                    // query parameratised with queryId
                    String qry = "SELECT RECORD_ID, USER_ID, OPERATION_CD, BUSCOMP_NAME, OPERATION_DT, FIELD_NAME, OLD_VAL, NEW_VAL, AUDIT_LOG, ROW_ID, BC_BASE_TBL FROM S_AUDIT_ITEM WHERE RECORD_ID='"
                            + queryId + "'";

                    try
                    {
                        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(qry);

                        result = XMLBuilder.xmlBuilder(results, queryId,
                            requestNumber);

                        // close the connection
                        stmt.close();
                        results.close();
                    }
                    catch (SQLException e)
                    {
                        String message = "A database error occurred : " + e;
                        XMLBuilder.dbError(message);
                    }



                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    String message = "A database error occurred : " + e;
                    XMLBuilder.dbError(message);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // log.error("Cannot connect to database :" + e);

                String message = "Unable to query the archive database : " + e;
                XMLBuilder.dbError(message);            
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // not sure if ever reached
            result = "The query parameter  is a null value";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

---

All information being returned is sent to **XMLBuilder** to be packaged into an XML however nothing is being returned. Meaning the function in my class is not being called when dealing with exceptions.

**XMLBuilder.dbError()**

```
public static String dbError(String message)
{
    //added uniquestring generator for id 
            String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    String result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?> "
            + "<SMessage MessageId=\"" + uniqueId + "\" MessageType=\"Integration Object\" IntObjectName=\"Test\" IntObjectFormat=\"Siebel Hierarchical\""
            + " ReturnCode=\"1\" ErrorMessage=\"Database error" + message + ".\">" +
    "</SMessage>";
    return result;
}
```

How can I get an error message returned so I can figure out whether this is a server error or it is my servlet

Thankyou

Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling this method:

```
XMLBuilder.dbError(message);
```

but not using its result. So the `result` variable remain blank, and that's what you return to the client.

I would rather throw all execptions (that you can't recover from) out to the top level request handler method (otherwise you'll duplicate all your XML marshalling invocations). Only then should you:

1. log that exception in your server logs
2. present an error to the client (via XML)

That would give you a more consistent (less repeated) means of handling errors, and you're not having to present an XML-wrapped error from the depths of your code.

As an aside, your code isn't thread-safe. You're calling 'static' methods on the class to set up connections etc. You'll be better off getting the connection, statement etc. all within one service method.

Comment: So result = XMLBuilder.dbError(message); ?

Comment: Thanks Brian, I am using this with an Oracle application called Siebel which is the client side. This handles all logging etc but do you think I should maintain a separate log for the back end? Thanks

Comment: I do. The server logs will act as a permanent record of errors recorded from your PoV. It will help reconcile issues and act as a log of errors encountered

Comment: Argh looks like im getting a nullpointerexception , not good :(

Comment: I suspect 'conn' is not being set. The connection method attempts to return an error, and consequently the conn variable may/may not be set.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21635/discussion-between-loosebruce-and-brian-agnew)